# Adding many relations when creating a record

Tags: custom-object, force.com, custom-field

How can I customize object or layout, to make it possible to select many related records when creating a new record?
I think we can select only one record for Lookup Relationship field as a default, but I want to select many somehow.

Comment: Can you please explain your use case and maybe attach a screenshot so others can understand what you want exactly?

Comment: Well, my case is such as managing contracts, which can sometimes be among three(or more?) parties.
Since it relates to more than one companies(other than self), I want to make it possible to select multiple companies as a related object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you have to build a custom junction object and write code to allow selecting multiple values. There's an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KQyHAAW) you can vote on for a future enhancement.

Comment: Is code you mean view?  
I don't understand why custom junction object is necessary if we write view for ourselves. Isn't lookup relation one-to-many relation as a model?

Comment: Lookup relationship is one to many for the child object. What you're looking for is a many-to-many relationship (n-to-n) to allow selecting multiple records that can be related to.